# IONIC 2: How to upload a .docx, image file on the remote server and link of file into mysql database

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an issue in uploading an .docx,image on the remote server with its link should save into the database. Please help me to solve this.
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Please convert your image to base64  bit format string and separately send image name to the server

Comment: But how can I save the link of the doc file?? Can u just show me the example code for it sir?

Comment: did u tried this solution 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Comment: Thank you @Sachin Gawai for solution, but I have solved with another way.

Comment: @TusharSaindane , it would be much appreciated if you can share the way you did, as I am having same problem with ionic 2

Comment: @ChiragPatel for late reply ,i am providing you my way ->  const `fileTransfer = new Transfer();
        var options: any;
        options = {
           fileKey: 'file',
           fileName: newFileName,
           mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            chunkedMode: false,
           headers: {'Content-Type' : undefined},
             params : {'fileName': newFileName}
           
        }       fileTransfer.upload(filePath, link,options)
         .then((data) => { use this function }); ` and in then function you can write php link to insert data in data database.

Comment: @ChiragPatel also u have to write one php to upload image..hope this will work u.. :)